# optimization in R across multiple 'areas'

Tags: r

I am building a bioeconomic model of a fishery with multiple areas and fleets. 
I need to add a cost function to the objective function.
The cost function derivative is:

```
dvcost<-(maxeff/(maxeff-(total f))*k*(f/total f)-ln(1-((total f)/maxeff))*k*maxeff/(total f)*(1-(f/total f))
```

where: for each fleet, f is effort in a specific area where the objective function is being minimized, total f is the sum of effort across areas for a particular fleet. k and maxeff are parameters.

My question is: how do I apply this cost function to my problem? I already have total f (which is 'f' in the code), but I need to find the f for the area that the objective function is working over.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

The full code is below:
***CODE***

```
nfleets<-2
nareas<-2
M<-1
M<-array(M,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
N<-1000
cost<-c(30,30)
cost<-array(cost,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
Price<-2
Price<-array(Price,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
q<-array(0.1,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
f<-1
f<-array(f,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
init.eff<-array(3,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
OF<-array(c(q*f), dim=c(nfleets, nareas))

Catch<-array(0,dim=c(nfleets, nareas))

obj<-function(f){
    f <- array(f, dim=c(nfleets, nareas)) 
    F <- q*f
    Z <- M+sum(F)
    S <- exp(-Z)
    Catch<- N*F/Z*(1-S)
    Tot.Catch <- sum(Catch)
    NR<-array(0,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
    NR<-Price*Catch - f*cost
    d.NR<-array(0,dim=c(nfleets,nareas))
    f <- apply(f, 1, sum)
    d.NR<- N*q/Z*(1-S-F/Z+F/Z*S+F*S)*Price - cost
    return(sum(d.NR*d.NR))
}
zero.bnd <-  rep.int(0, length(f))
opt.eff  <- optim( init.eff, obj, method="Nelder-Mead" )
```